# Change class on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm aware there´s a few answers on this question. but I cant't get it to work with my script. I want to change class the `.icon-menu` element when clicked. what's the correct practice here?

```
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
        left: "0px"
    }, 200);
    $('body').animate({
        left: "500px"
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: `$(".icon-menu").addClass("className");`

Comment: What exactly you want to do? to add another class use ^^^^^^

Comment: change class of what?? `body` or `.menu`??

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, what are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you have 2 functions to add and remove classes -> addClass() -> removeClass(). So if you want to change it you have to remove a class and add different one.

In click function you will have your ".icon-menu" element in $(this) variable. So you should do it inside a click like this:

```
$(this).removeClass('yourClassToRemove');
$(this).addClass('yourClassToAdd');
```

Or in simpler one-line way it should work like that:

```
$(this).removeClass('yourClassToRemove').addClass('yourClassToAdd');
```

Links to Jquery Api:

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to permanently add the class use :

```
$(".icon-menu").addClass("className");
```

Or If you want to toggle the class

```
 $(".icon-menu").toggle("className");
```

Comment: the 2nd one should be `toggleClass` if am not wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `addClass` method.

```
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("class");
    // or
    $(this).toogleClass("class");
}
```